# What is the best path for working with 3d graphics?

Tags: c, opengl, 3d

Right now, I think a combination of C and openGL is what I need to learn, but it seems like there is still more to it that I need. Also, I'm not sure where to start. I know some C, from reading *the C Programming Language* (K&R).

Answer (score 11):

If you understand the concepts behind 3D computer graphics then OpenGL + C is about all you need.  If you need some help with the concepts then I'd suggest the [NeHe OpenGL tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) and a good reference book like [The Red Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321481003).

Comment: I'd also recommend picking up the OpenGL SuperBible.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are trying to do:

- If games interest you and you just want to develop amateur stuff without all the fuss, XNA + C# is by far the easiest way to start.
- If you plan on becoming a professional game developer, your best bet is DirectX + C++.
- If you like open source and just want to mess around with general 3D, OpenGL + C/C++ will offer you a nice community of dedicated people.

There are of course a number of engines and library you can use on top of the last two, such as Torque, Geometric Tools, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look at .NET possibilities, i.e [XNA Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/xna/default.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, but I only want to use code where source is available to modify.

Comment: I don't see how that prevents use of XNA.  The library iteslf may not be open source, but you can write whatever code you want to hit it.  It's not like you can modify OpenGL's code either.

Comment: Can't I download openGL's source?

Comment: There is no real openGL source you can grab.  OpenGL is just the API to the graphics card.  The implementations are generally specific to the graphics card and are part of the drivers.  Most of those are closed.  You'll get headers so you can link to the drivers, but that's about it.  There are some opensource libraries on top of OpenGL, but OpenGL itself really just defines the API you use to hit the graphics card.

Comment: Well, there's always Mesa ( http://www.mesa3d.org/ ) which implements a complete OpenGL stack in software (including GLSL).  You'd have to have pretty minimal performance requirements or be a hardcore FOSS fanatic to prefer it over a proprietary hardware accelerated OpenGL though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is more to it. What makes you think so ?
C and OpenGL is enough to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using 3D Studio Max and actually making models helped a lot when it came to learning some OpenGL. I could understand all the intricacies with normals and whatnot.

I would really recommend against trying to learn C and OpenGL at the same time. They are both complicated and more so when you mix them.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend extremely highly getting, reading, and working through some of the examples in the book [Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201848406).  Yes, the book is MASSIVELY out of date; it's still the canonical reference for this sort of thing.